# Cannot use pointer on FilterRowSet?

Tags: java, jdbc, rowset, cachedrowset

I'm trying to use FilterRowSet to filter the appropriate values from database query. This is my code:

```
// Initialize
FilteredRowSet rowset = new FilteredRowSetImpl();

// Set the query string
rowset.setCommand("SELECT * FROM student");
rowset.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test");
rowset.setUsername("root");
rowset.setPassword("");

// Execute to get a result set
rowset.execute();

System.out.println(rowset.first()); // Output: true
rowset.setFilter(new MyStringFilter("matcher", "column_name")); // Add condition to my filter rowset
System.out.println(rowset.first()); // Output: false
```

The problem is my rowset's pointer cannot be set after I set the filter condition, which is making it impossible to parse through it (or something similar) at later point of time.

Is this a bug or something that I am not aware of, when using the FilteredRowSet class?

Comment: That code doesn't demonstrate a problem, could you be more specific as to 1) what happens and 2) what you expect. Because based on your code I'd say it works fine (hint: `first()` moves the resultset/rowset to the first row and returns true if there is a row).

Comment: Oops, sorry. The second time, output should be false ;)

Comment: But why should it be false? Do you expect that the filter will filter out all rows? Because after applying the filter, the rowset will behave as if it only has those filtered rows, so a call to `first()` will move to the first row that matches the filter (if any).

Comment: I has just edited my question above. I expected to get a true output after set a filter condition, but actually i cannot reset the pointer to the head of the result set (you can see that the output of the second time is false). And sorry for my bad english, if that led to misunderstanding.

Comment: What's `MyStringFilter`?

Comment: Just a filter class implements from Predicate. It used to describe the rule(s) to filter out inappropriate values.